# Compare two DataTable Multi fields

Tags: .net, ado.net, dataset

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        dt1.Columns.Add("id");
        dt2.Columns.Add("id");

        dt1.Columns.Add("val1");
        dt2.Columns.Add("val1");

        dt1.Columns.Add("val2");
        dt1.Columns.Add("val2");


        dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "a", "a1" });
        dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "b", "b1" });
        dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "", "b", "b1" });
        dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "4", "", "c1" });


        dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "a", "a1" });
        dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "b", "b1" });
        dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] { "3", "c", "c1" });
        dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] { "3", "c", "c1" });
        dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] { "4", "d", "d1" });
        dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] { "5", "e", "e1" });
```

result should contain only values which are not present in dt1. Can we do this with linq

Comment: Do you have to use DataTables to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with LINQ, I'd do this:

```
var dataRows1 = st1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { 
    Id = r["id"], Val1 = r["val1"], Val2 = r["val2"] });

var dataRows2 = st2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { 
    Id = r["id"], Val1 = r["val1"], Val2 = r["val2"] });
```

This gives you [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) of anonymous types which can be compared against.  Then, you can do this:

```
var dt2NotInDt1 = dataRows2.Where(r2 => !dataRows1.Any(r1 => r1.Equals(r2));
```

Note, that this assumes that your comparison criteria is all the values in the rows (`id` included).

Also note the call to [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx).  Anonymous types override the `Equals` method to provide a value comparison across all the properties of the anonymous type.  From the ["Anonymous Types" section of the C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Because the `Equals` and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods of the
>   properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
>   all their properties are equal.

You can simplify this logic depending on what the constraints are.  For example, if there is  a primary key (or some sort of unique row identifier) you could place the rows in a dictionary keyed on that value and then perform the lookup based on that.

In your case, assuming `id` is unique, you could do this (after the first two lines at the top):

```
var dataRows1Map = dataRows1.ToDictionary(r => r.Id);
```

That will give you a map which you can then do a lookup on (I'm switching to query syntax, as I believe it's a little more readable here).

```
var dt2NotInDt1 = 
    for r2 in dataRows2
    let r1Exists = dataRows1Map.ContainsKey(r2.Id)
    let r1 = r1Exists ? dataRows1Map[r2.Id] : null
    where 
        // Rows that don't have a primary key in the first set.
        !r1Exists ||
        // Rows that are different.
        !r1.Equals(r2)
    select r2;
```